# Get the users associated with Database

Tags: powershell

I am new to power shell and I read in few blogs that it is mainly meant for automation. I have a requirement where I need to generate the audit report for SQL which should shows that who are  the users for a particular database. This would help me to remove the people who are no more in my organisation.

The format I needed was as below:

```
DatabaseName Users  Role/ Permission
X            DEF    Public
X            ABC    SYS Admin
Y            DEF    Public
```

I have gone through few blogs and I am able to connect remote server database but I dont know how to extract the users.Can any one advise me whether we can automate this report using power shell to extract the report .

Please let me know if you need any other details.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a good question. This one is lacking a lot of context. Which part, exactly, are you having problems with? Can you create the report with manual steps? Can you connect to the database with Powershell?

Comment: Define "associated with the database". Do you want a report on database users? System users? Both? And what database (or rather DBMS) in the first place?

Comment: I am really sorry and I know mistake is from my side.. The question was written  by my friend . I have edited the question now. Hope it is ok now.. As always thanks fr your guidance and advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function SQL-Get-Logins
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Returns a list of SQL Server logins defined on the specified server/instance.

    .DESCRIPTION
    This function returns a complete list of all logins defined for the specified
    server/instance, including the login type, the default database, and the server
    role.

    .PARAMETER server
    The computer hosting SQL Server.

    .PARAMETER instance
    The instance to be used on that server.

    .PARAMETER saPassword
    The 'sa' password on that server\instance

    .EXAMPLE
    SQL-Get-Logins myserver myinstance sa | %{ Write-Host $_.LoginName }
    #>

    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $server,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $instance  = 'MSSQL',
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $saPassword
    )

    $logins = $null

    try
    {
        $query = @"
        select a.name as LoginName, a.type_desc as LoginType, a.default_database_name as DefaultDBName,
        case when b.sysadmin = 1 THEN 'sysadmin'
                  when b.securityadmin=1 THEN 'securityadmin'
                  when b.serveradmin=1 THEN 'serveradmin'
                  when b.setupadmin=1 THEN 'setupadmin'
                  when b.processadmin=1 THEN 'processadmin'
                  when b.diskadmin=1 THEN 'diskadmin'
                  when b.dbcreator=1 THEN 'dbcreator'
                  when b.bulkadmin=1 THEN 'bulkadmin'
                  else 'Public' end as ServerRole
        from sys.server_principals a join master..syslogins b on a.sid=b.sid where a.type  <> 'R' and a.name not like '##%'
"@

        $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$server\$instance;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=$saPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;"
        $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter ($query, $sqlConnection)
        $dataSet = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
        $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null 

        $logins = $dataSet.Tables[0]

        foreach ($login in $logins)
        {
            $loginName = $login.ItemArray[0]
            $loginType = $login.ItemArray[1]
            $defaultDbName = $login.ItemArray[2]
            $serverRole = $login.ItemArray[3]

            Write-Output "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): LoginName: $loginName, LoginType: $loginType, Default database: $defaultDbName, Server Role: $serverRole"
        }
    }

    catch
    {
        Write-Error "$($MyInvocation.InvocationName): $_"
    }

    return $logins
}
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your solution.Will try that let you know.